# Conditional style inside an element

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

How do I do a conditional style based on a MODEL value. Such as below, I want the column either Green or Orange based on a value from the Model

```
<div class="col-6" 
     @Model.QuestionAnswers[i].answers[j].answerSelected == true 
           ? style="background-color:green" 
           : style="background-color:darkorange">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
<div class="col-6" 
     style="@(Model.QuestionAnswers[i].answers[j].answerSelected == true ? "background-color: green;" : "background-color: darkorange;")">
```

But its cleaner to create a variable for the calculated style:

```
@{
    var calculatedStyle = Model.QuestionAnswers[i].answers[j].answerSelected == true ? "background-color: green;" : "background-color: darkorange;";
}
<div class="col-6" style="@calculatedStyle">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your strings into quotes:

```
<div class="col-6" @(Model.QuestionAnswers[i].answers[j].answerSelected == true ? "style=\"background-color:green\"" : "style=\"background-color:darkorange\"")>
```